# How to change profile licence type

Tags: profile

Is there any way to change the Profile licence type by editing the profile?

Is there any other way to change the profile licence without creating a new profile from scratch?

Answer (score 4):

When you go to profiles in the setup and create a new profile it will ask you to clone it from a particular profile that is already there. You can then pick a profile that has the required licence already. There will always be some tweaking of the profile. You can not clone a profile that has a different licence type and change this. (I've tried it myself)

I haven't tried it, but you could try to go to the salesforce IDE and edit the xml of the profile.
It has an entry 
`<userLicense>Salesforce Platform</userLicense>`
Change this and see what happens (on a sandbox of course!)

EDIT:
I've just tried it, but you can't change the licence type with the Force.com IDE.

Answer (score 1):

No , You cant Change UserLicense even through XML. I have Checked it Manualy by Apex Code and also by XML updation(Called File based Metadata Using Force.com IDE)[You Can See this Image. I have Use this process for Created and also for cloned profile]
 https://i.stack.imgur.com/JmE4a.png

Comment: I wonder if it's possible to create a new profile for the license type you want, then copy/paste the xml from the existing profile over (sans the <userLicense> tag)... will try now and report back!

Comment: So to follow up - it is indeed possible to copy XML from the existing profile to a new profile of the correct license type... it's just a bit of a process, since you need to retrieve/deploy the new profile with the relevant metadata you're updating permissions on... eg you need to pull custom objects and fields if you want to update profile object CRUDs and field level security.

Answer (score 0):

Idea Posted On Idea Exchange:

> > https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000Z6gBAAS
> >     https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000l0eSAAQ

Answer (score 0):

You can't change it via an IDE but you can clone it, then delete the first one.  Disclaimer : That won't be perfect !

- In VsCode retrieve the profile *with all the metadata involved in the profile* (Apex classes, CustomObjects...) to be sure that your profile xml will be as complete as possible. To do that use a package.xml to be sure you'll get that metadata in a single operation.
- Clone the file, give it a new name, change the licence in the xml
- Deploy the new file with the same package.xml file.

Of courses the permissions in the profile have to be compatible with the new licence

I wasn't able to deploy the standard objects with the profile though, don't know why.

Be sure it's worth it, you'll meet a lot of errors and will waste a lot of time. But if you have custom objects with many fields with specific permissions, you might save some time with this method.