# I want to clone a standard Profile but with different User license

Tags: profile, licenses, userlicense

I want to clone a standard Profile but with different User license.
Is it possible ?

Comment: No you cannot. Check this link..http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/18306/how-to-change-profile-licence-type

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible with Salesforce, a standard Profile can only be cloned to the same User Licence type. [Salesforce Help Entry](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=users_profiles_cloning.htm)

To create a profile with a set of permissions that matched the particular profile for a different User Licence Type would have to be done manually.